# Create order per product item on Magento [ask]

Tags: magento, orders

Can we create the order per product item on Magento when we go to checkout process..?
For example :

If on my shopping cart, I've 2 products, so the order is separates into 2 orders..

Thanks..

Comment: You can always get all cart products and based on them, create orders in `foreach` loop.

Comment: Thanks for the response..I know that, but where I put the code,